# Rails is displaying an empty value and an id in my model view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, erb

[image: List view]

I've a rails view that outputs the content of a model value in this case agenda.subject

Checking the db the bottom two items are not in the db, I know :id and the blank are but what in my code could cause it to display like this

users/index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <%= render 'agendas/agenda_form' %>
        <% if @user.agendas.any? %>
            <h2>Agendas (<%= @user.agendas.count %>)</h2>
            <ol class="agendas">
                <%= render @agendas %>
            </ol>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

the _agenda.html.erb partial
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= agenda.subject %></span>
  <%= link_to 'delete', agenda, method: :delete,
                                confirm: "You Sure?",
                                title: agenda.subject %>
</li>
```

and the users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @agenda = current_user.agendas.build if signed_in?
    @agendas = current_user.agendas
  end
end
```

.... user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, #] 8

[`#<Agenda id: 49, subject: "Ut qui vel eos quia vitae.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, #<Agenda id: 43, subject: "Enim dolorem.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, #<Agenda id: 37, subject: "Rerum architecto est nihil totam.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, #<Agenda id: 31, subject: "Non.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, #<Agenda id: 25, subject: "Libero enim et explicabo.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, #<Agenda id: 19, subject: "Et molestiae et quia saepe quia.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, #<Agenda id: 7, subject: "Eum consectetur iste.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, #<Agenda id: nil, subject: nil, due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>] 8`

I excluded the first couple of records they looked normal but its those last 2 that are weird
Output from @agendas.inspect and @agendas.length

I am using faker to create a sample data fro the app, possibly culprit?

Comment: Can you print what `@agendas.inspect` and `@agendas.length` are just before the loop is called?

Comment: editied question with above requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling

```
current_user.agendas.build current_user.agendas.build
```

which will append a blank, unsaved agenda to the list of agendas whenever a signed in used views this page. It's not clear from your question what you do with `@agenda` but you may be better off just setting that to `Agenda.new`

Comment: That seemed to do it, changed to @agenda = Agenda.new, not sure why it worked but side question, how is current_user.agendas.build producing the blank unsaved agenda

Comment: That's what build does: it adds an unsaved agenda to the collection

Answer (score 1):

Thanks -

Given your test data of:

```
[#<Agenda id: 49, subject: "Ut qui vel eos quia vitae.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, 
#<Agenda id: 43, subject: "Enim dolorem.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, 
#<Agenda id: 37, subject: "Rerum architecto est nihil totam.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, 
#<Agenda id: 31, subject: "Non.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, 
#<Agenda id: 25, subject: "Libero enim et explicabo.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, 
#<Agenda id: 19, subject: "Et molestiae et quia saepe quia.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, 
#<Agenda id: 7, subject: "Eum consectetur iste.", due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22", updated_at: "2012-05-17 15:52:22">, 
#<Agenda id: nil, subject: nil, due_date: nil, completed: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

It looks as if the culprit is in the data. I'd recommend confirming that you're actually generating the data that you think you are.